# Using sizeof() for integer array?

Tags: c

```
// Buffer size
#define BUFSIZE (32)

// The buffer 
int buf[BUFSIZE];

// Clearing the buffer:

// 1st way
memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(int)); 

// or

// 2nd way
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

To get the size of the buffer in bytes, needed for `memset`, should `sizeof` be called on the `int` (1st way) or on the array (2nd way)? Does it matter?

Comment: In this specific case it doesn't matter. When it *does* matter if is the array have decayed to a pointer (to its first element).

Comment: As an alternative, you could set all elements to zero when defining the array: `int buf[BUFSIZE] = { 0 };`

Comment: It's a member of a struct, so can't set to zero when defining.

Comment: @Danijel if I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, can you just do `struct {int arr[10];} foo = {.arr = {0}};` (Or just `struct {/*...*/} foo = {0}`)? Or is this not possible for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the second variant.

It is more robust to changes of array size or type:
The first variant will fail if:

```
int buf[NEW_BUFSIZE]; // changed size
memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(int)); // will partially initialize or overflow
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));  // works fine
```

or

```
new_type buf[BUFSIZE]; // changed type
memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(int)); // will partially initialize or overflow
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));  // works fine
```

BTW.

There is no need to use parenthesizes in `sizeof` if an operand is an expression. `sizeof buf` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the first. Because if you change the allocation from

```
int buf[BUFSIZE];
```

to

```
int *buf = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof*buf);
```

then the second one (`sizeof buf`)doesn't give the *array* size.

To avoid dependencies (`buf` knows its contents' type, even as pointer) and the parens:

```
memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE * sizeof*buf)
```

And: BUF**SIZE** can be misleading, since it is the number of elements, not the sizeof-array-size. `LEN(GTH)` is an alternative.

Comment: why not use `calloc()` in the first place?

Comment: That would not be a general solution. And I just changed that single line. OP also has two steps insetad of `= {0}`.

Comment: But of course your A is the correct one :) I just wanted to show another side.